# writing to FILE for transmission over USART

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I have a bit of code written by someone else that I'm trying to understand. I'm familiar with c enough to make basic/intermediate functions, but never really learned to use the FILE handler.
The code relates to how i use/initialise the USART on an ATMEL microcontroller, and I am adding comments to every line to help keep track, but i'm struggling a little with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int USART_0_printCHAR(char character, FILE *stream) // character =  the received character, FILE = reference file, *stream = pointer
{
    USART_Transmit_Char(character); //send the character over USART
    return 0; // return 0 to the caller for exit success.
}

FILE USART_0_stream = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(USART_0_printCHAR, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE); //what do these arguments mean? is it replacing a standard output stream with the character that is written to the buffer.

void USART_Transmit_Char(char data)
{
// code omitted: 
// check the Transmit buffer
// wait for free space in the buffer
// put the character into the buffer
// enable the Data Register Empty Interrupt for TX
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unless this is an established library, which I doubt, then nobody can answer the question without viewing the source of those functions. Using `FILE` from stdio.h for the purpose of UART communication is weird an very likely needlessly complex. Hacking together a simple UART driver isn't rocket science.

Comment: This is the method of **avr-libc** to use `FILE` controlled streams and depending functions like `fprintf()` and friends. Please read the documentation. -- In most cases, you can ignore the stream pointer. In some cases, you can use it to differentiate multiple streams, like virtual serial communication over USB and a display. I did this many years ago.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, yeah I had the question in the code. i should have moved that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example initializes the default stream for the standard IO facilities. It creates a write only stream that writes its output to `USART_0_printCHAR`.

See [Standard IO facilities](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaf41f158c022cbb6203ccd87d27301226)

> The standard streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are provided, but contrary to the C standard, since avr-libc has no knowledge about applicable devices, these **streams are not already pre-initialized at application startup**. Also, since there is no notion of "file" whatsoever to avr-libc, there is no function fopen() that could be used to associate a stream to some device. (See note 1.) Instead, **the function fdevopen() is provided to associate a stream to a device, where the device needs to provide a function to send a character,** to receive a character, or both.

> As an alternative method to fdevopen(), **the macro fdev_setup_stream() might be used to setup a user-supplied FILE structure**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);
static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL,
                                         _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
static int
uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
  if (c == '\n')
    uart_putchar('\r', stream);
  loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, UDRE);
  UDR = c;
  return 0;
}
int
main(void)
{
  init_uart();
  stdout = &mystdout;
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

> This example uses the **initializer form FDEV_SETUP_STREAM()** rather than the function-like fdev_setup_stream(), so all data initialization happens during C start-up.

Comment: i did come across that on a website somewhere, but didnt quite understand it...so, allow me see if I have this understood. **FILE** is just the convenient object for storing the data, and is given the name **USART_0_stream**. The character in **USART_0_printCHAR** is pointed to the **FILE**. The called function takes the character and runs it through some conditions to determine if it is written to USART or not, and thus written to **FILE**. As i only have the put argument and get argument is NULL, the stream has write intent only, so i'm not reading anything off it, just writing to it.

Comment: FILE is a struct type that holds data to be used by the IO facilities. FDEV_SETUP_STREAM is just a convenient way to initialize a struct of that type. One of the struct members is a pointer to a function that is then used to write data. This would `uart_putchar` is my example. So each time something is written to this stream, the respective function is called and writes the data to the UART. It makes sense to specify the stream as write only if you only supply a write function. Other parts of a program may check this information if a stream can read and/or write and use it accordingly.